# Optaplanner: Force to use max vehicles

Tags: java, routes, optaplanner

I am trying to implement optaplanner on a real case I and I need to force the solver to use all vehicles. Is this possible? I understand the solvers is returning the best solution, but for me I need to optimize the total routes for all the given vehicles.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I conclude that **your** best solution isn't the solution where the total traveled distance (and hence most probably also the total cost) is minimised, but where all vehicle's total distances are as close as possible to the "average" distance of all vehicle's ?

Then I guess you should make a constraint penalising, for each vehicle, the difference of it's traveled distance with the average of all vehicle's traveled distance. And **also** a constraint penalising all vehicles with a total travel distance of 0 kilometers (or miles, as you prefer).

Comment: Agreed. In that new constraint, I would even square the distance of each vehicle (or the difference of each vehicle's distance with the average distance per vehicle). See https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html.

Comment: Although I suspect you don't want distance, you want "working time" (= travel time + service time), basically you want to load balance when they get back the depot (presuming they all left at the same time). Anyway same trick: penalize `workingTime * workingtime`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I noticed that on the demo something that I would like to understand. I have 13 Vehicles and the solution is to give me 6 Vehicles with 6h travel time. If I add one more vehicle (14) the solver will start again and eventually it will give me a better solution comparing to the first one. 13 vehicles and 5h. Why?